# Heatmap as background of a Plot in matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot, heatmap

I have following plot:

[image: figure1]

which has been generated with this code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ttc = pd.read_excel("../XLSX_Files/Baseline_Data.xlsx", sheet_name="Data")["TTC"]
risks = col.OrderedDict(
[("very low", 0), ("low", 0), ("medium-to-low", 0), ("medium", 0), ("high-to-medium", 0), ("high", 0),
 ("very high", 0)])

---- Part in which risks get filled --- 

for x in risks:
     risk_distribution.append(float(risks[x]) / len(ttc))

x = np.arange(1, len(risks) + 1)
y = np.arange(0.0, 0.4, 0.05)
xticks = risks.keys()
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, risk_distribution)
ax.set_ylim(0, 0.4)
plt.show()
```

So my actual question is: How can I add a risk heatmap as background (the same as this one: https://www.latestquality.com/risk-heat-map/)

What I've tried to far:

```
import seaborn as sns
risk_heatmap = [
    [1.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0.3, 0, 0, 0],
    [1.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.5, 0, 0],
    [1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0, 0],
    [2.0, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0],
    [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.2, 1.2, 0.7, 0.7]
 ]

ax = sns.heatmap(risk_heatmap, linewidth=0.5, cbar=False, cmap="RdYlGn")
```

But this gives me some weird looking graph. [image]

Is there a possible way to add the heatmap without losing the y dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are running into is that the y scales are not necessarily going to match. You need to overlay 2 axes that share the same x axis. You can use `matplotlib.axes.Axes.twinx` to accomplish this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
risk_heatmap = [
    [1.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0.3, 0, 0, 0],
    [1.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.5, 0, 0],
    [1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0, 0],
    [2.0, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 0.7, 0.7, 0],
    [2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 1.2, 1.2, 0.7, 0.7]
 ]

ax1 = sns.heatmap(risk_heatmap, linewidth=0.5, cbar=False, cmap="RdYlGn")

ax2 = ax1.twinx()
ax2.plot(np.random.random(7) * .3)
ax2.set_ylim(0, 0.4)

plt.show()
```

Here is another [example](https://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html).